How can I take an image that has GPS EXIF information in Flutter
I am trying to see if there is a way I can take an image that has GPS information (Latitude & Longitude) in it's EXIF data from my flutter app. Or if there is a way to manually add GPS information to my image.
I use the package camera to capture an image in my app. The captured image comes as an XFile. I want to add GPS information to the image EXIF data. OR, capture an image with GPS location when the user triggers the capture action.
I have looked around for a solution, but all I seem to find is reading EXIF information from the photo. I don't want to read right now, I want to write EXIF information to the image.
